# Hacer una comparación de array y comprobación de rol de usuario

Tags: php

en mi proyecto tengo que realizar unos cambos automaticos en wordpress para que si un usuario ha subido un producto en woocommerce cambie su ROL.

Para ello he realizado este codigo

```
<?php
/*
Hemos de hacer el proceso de conectarnos a la BBDD, obtener todos los usuarios y obtener sus ID
Realizar un for con todo el array de iD empezando por 3 y asi quino y aitor siguen siendo administradores
Realiar lo mismo un for y un if para saber si han patrocinado o no a alguien con el id_patrocinador de los demas usuarios.
*/
//variables y conexion mysql
$hostname="localhost";
$username="myinvestpa";
$password="jPd4qB06";
$dbname="investpainbbdd";

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

//Realizamos la consulta sql y la ordenamos ascendiente

$query = "SELECT ID FROM wp_users WHERE ID IN(SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type= 'product') AND ID NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' and meta_value LIKE '%\"Administrator\"%')";//Seleccionamos los id de los usuarios que han escrito un post de tipo product
$results1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('ok');
$fila = mysqli_fetch_row($results1);

for($i=0;$i<=mysqli_fetch_row($results1);$i++){ 
//UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='a:1:{s:13:&quot;administrator&quot;;b:1;}' WHERE user_id=2 AND meta_key='wp_capabilities'  
//a:1:{s:6:"asesor";b:1;}
//a:1:{s:6:"vendor";b:1;}
//a:1:{s:26:"asesor_mandatariopropiedad";b:1;}
$query2 ="UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value='a:1:{s:6:"'vendor'";b:1;}' WHERE user_id='".$fila[$i]."' AND meta_key='wp_capabilities'";
$results2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die('ok');
}
// Hemos de distinguir ahora entre si es usuario, asesor para depende de que usuario sea añadir mandatario o asesor mandatario y luego como se ejecuta este php solo


/*
$results1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('ok');
$fila = mysqli_fetch_row($results1);*/
?>
```

Con este código obtenemos los id de los usuarios que han escrito un post de tipo producto y que no son administradores.

Ahora he de saber si ese usuario es asesor o un usuario normal debido a que es asesor he de cambiar el rol a asesor-mandatario y si es solo usuario a mandatario.

Comment: Si tienes ambos datos en un arreglo puedes usar la funcion array_diff para ver en que difieren ambos. Solo en caso de que sean arreglos de enteros, debido a que almacenas ids en ellos

Comment: Mejor usa un join desde MySQL donde la comparación que quieres hacer con arreglos en php te lo haga el motor de tu base de datos, así te ahorrarás horas de código en PHP

Comment: Vale, la dificultad es que hay dos usuarios con id 1 e id2 que no han de cambiar de rol ya que son amdministrador es por ello que he hecho el for

Answer (score 2):

Con una consulta es mejor. Solo haga esta consulta y de ahí le mostrará el ID de los usuario que coinciden con los de un post y además podría obtener más datos de usuario si así lo desea.

```
        SELECT ID  FROM wp_users WHERE ID IN(SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type= 'product');

        o con un JOIN

        SELECT ID  FROM wp_users AS wpu INNER JOIN wp_posts AS wpp ON(wpu.ID=wpp.post_author );

        --------------CON LIMITACIÓN DE USUARIOS------------
        SELECT id FROM wp_users WHERE user_type NOT IN ( 'admin', 'super_usuario', 'otro_usuario') AND  id  IN(SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type= 'product');

        o con un JOIN

        SELECT ID FROM wp_users AS wpu INNER JOIN wp_posts AS wpp ON(wpu.ID=wpp.post_author ) 
        WHERE user_type NOT IN ( 'admin', 'super_usuario', 'otro_usuario');
```

Comment: vale, el problema es que hay dos usuarios que soy yo y otro que no han de cambiar de rol por eso hago el for

Comment: He probado la consulta y me da los id que han escrito un post con post type product cierto? entonces si quiero coger solo los id diferentes a 1 y 2 y cambiarles el usuario como lo haria? tal cual estoy haciendo en el for?

Comment: Jonatahn tu respuesta va bien, podrias agregar a tu consulta como excluir de los id devueltos los usuarios administrador? algo asi como  id not in (select id form wp_users where user_type != 'admin') (es la idea, no conozco las tablas exactas de memoria)...

Comment: Sí, es una consulta normal:

SELECT id FROM wp_users WHERE user_type NOT IN ( 'admin', 'super_usuario', 'otro_usuario') AND  id  IN(SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type= 'product');

o con un JOIN

SELECT ID FROM wp_users AS wpu INNER JOIN wp_posts AS wpp ON(wpu.ID=wpp.post_author ) 
WHERE user_type NOT IN ( 'admin', 'super_usuario', 'otro_usuario');

Comment: Con el user_type no ahora pongo la respuesta

Comment: La pregunta esta editada con el query correcto